# WCF REST returning 401 Not authorize response with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, authentication

I have two applications:

1. Web Application deployed at Windows Server 2008 R2 server. This application serves as endpoint for WCF REST calls.
2. Windows Forms Desktop C# application which will make REST calls to web application above. This application is also running on same Windows Server 2008 R2 server machine.

Everything works fine if I have the Web application using Forms Authentication but as I change its authentication to Windows, the REST calls stop working and it starts getting 401 not authorized response from Web application.

Here are some details of my web application:

The WebHttpBinding for WCF is set to "WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly" with credentials as HttpClientCredentialType.Windows.

```
 this.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
 this.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

Web.config of this website is having:

```
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

IIS authentication setting for this site:

[image]

Providers for Windows Authentication is set to "Negotiate":

[image]

To investigate further I tried to debug the application and noticed that the REST calls are able to reach the BeginRequest method of Global.asax but after executing that method the 401 response is returned to client. I am not able to reach even to the ServiceAuthorizationManager as the 401 response is returned before that.

I have tried all the following WCF REST calls: GET, PUT and POST to this application from Windows Forms C# client and all of them are returned as 401 Not authorized from server.

**The same C# client gets the desired response from web application works when I change the authentication mode of web application from Windows to Forms.**

I would like to add more information on the above case. 
Even with the Windows Authentication mode of web application if I try to request the server with a REST call directly via web browser (Chrome in my case) I can get the response. The issue is coming only when I make the REST call from C# Windows Forms client. I guess it works in this case where I make REST call directly from browser because the Browser must be sending some authorization header to the server to process the request.

Can you help me with the case where REST calls are made from a client other than browser?

How do I let the REST calls from clients to hit the WCF REST end points instead of being getting 401 responses from server?

Comment: I got the solution finally!! Network credentials should be sent along with the request. Like this:
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;